# Select Files Based on Name

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find

I have a folder which has many thousands of files with names like: 
`feed_1.txt, feed_2.txt, feed_3.txt`

How do I select only files which are `feed_40000.txt` and higher?

Comment: You might consider `awk` for that

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: jww im sorry i dont understand your objection can you please explain

Answer (score 3):

You can use the find regex switch:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/feed_([4-9]|[123][0-9])[0-9]{4,}\.txt"
```

Comment: awesome answer sir, never knew that this option is also present in find, very nice thanks for sharing it.

Comment: `-regextype` is GNU find only as a note.

Comment: @dawg: by default the regextype is emacs, you can always write the regex like this without using this switch that is used here only to shorten the pattern: `.*/feed_\([4-9]\|[123][0-9]\)[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+\.txt`

Comment: @dawg: but it's clear that, in a more general case, that it's easier to pipe/exec the find command to or to use a language/tool able to do a number comparison. The regex is simple for `40+` but becomes more complicated for `43217` *(but not inefficient however)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` based check to get filename with values `>= 40000`:

```
printf "%s\n" feed_[0-9]* | awk -F '[_.]+' '$2 >= 40000'
```

To loop these filenames use:

```
while read -r file; do
   printf "processing %s\n" "$file"
done < <(printf "%s\n" feed_[0-9]* | awk -F '[_.]+' '$2 >= 40000')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
find . -type f -name "feed_*" | awk -F"_" '$2+0>=40000' # => list of file names...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a regex solution:

```
/feed_([4-9][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{5,})\.txt/g
```

This will match strings that fit either of two formats:

`feed_ab.txt`, where `a` is a digit from `4-9` and b is four digits (for the case where 40000 <= the number <= 99999, or

`feed_cd.txt`, where `c` is a digit from `1-9` and d is five or more digits (for the case where 100000 <= the number).

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is my approach too(as a learning and experiment with exec and awk). Following is the command.

```
find -type f  -exec awk --re-interval 'FILENAME ~ /feed_[4-9][0-9]{4,}.txt/ && !a[FILENAME]++{;print FILENAME} END{if(FILENAME ~ /feed_[4-9][0-9]{4,}.txt/ && !a[FILENAME]++){print FILENAME}}' {} \;
```

So following are the points on same.

I- First thing I used --re-interval for supporting {4,} to find the 4 continuous occurrences of 0-9 digits but in a newer version of awk this could be removed.

II- 1 more learning which I got it

```
a- When using \; at last of command it will read the empty size files BUT

b- When using \+ it will NOT display the 0 size files BECAUSE

c- We all know \+ collects all the files first then it will perform mentioned action in single shot, so obviously END section will pick only the last file and other files which have ZERO size will NEVER be read.
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of command too now.

```
find -type f  -exec awk --re-interval \
 'FILENAME ~ /feed_[4-9][0-9]{4,}.txt/ && !a[FILENAME]++{;print FILENAME} \
 END{if(FILENAME ~ /feed_[4-9][0-9]{4,}.txt/ && !a[FILENAME]++){print FILENAME}}' {} \;
```